# AWS boto3 - InvalidToken Error when calling the GetObject operation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, aws-sam

I'm currently trying to invoke a lambda function locally through the `sam local invoke` command, but I keep getting the InvalidToken error with the GetObject operation.

**What I've tried:**

- Since I'm operating everything on `ap-northeast-2` region, I double-checked that
  my config file `.aws` folder was set to the same region.
- I've tried printing (although not recommended) the credentials through the boto3 Session and confirmed that the credentials used are the same as the one in the credentials folder (the only credential there)
- I've tried adding the `--region ap-northeast-2` flag in my invocation command, but it gave the same error.
- I've checked the current user has full access to S3 resources (it has an Admin role). I've also tried detaching & reattaching roles (deleting the config & credentials files and running `aws configure` again with another admin role) but had no luck.

Could there be anything else that I might have forgotten?
Below are the code and the log output. Thanks in advance :)

```
# imports omitted
logger.info('Starting...')
s3 =  boto3.client('s3')
logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

session = boto3.Session()
credentials = session.get_frozen_credentials()
print(credentials.access_key, credentials.secret_key, credentials.token)

def load_model(): # handler function 
    logger.info('Loading model from S3')
    obj = s3.get_object(Bucket=MODEL_BUCKET, Key=MODEL_KEY )
    # obj = s3.Object(bucket_name='ml-project-paul-kang', key='fastai-models/lesson1/model.tar.gz')
    logger.info('Model loading complete')
    bytestream = io.BytesIO(obj['Body'].read()) # further code omitted
```

And this is what I get after running `sam local invoke PyTorchFunction -n env.json -e event.json`:

```
Invoking app.lambda_handler (python3.6)
arn:aws:lambda:ap-northeast-2:<ID>:layer:pytorch-p36:1 is already cached. Skipping download
Requested to skip pulling images ...

[INFO]  2020-08-22T08:18:22.685Z                Starting...
<CURRENT_USER_ACCESS_KEY> <CURRENT_USER_SECRET_KEY> (null)
[INFO]  2020-08-22T08:18:22.685Z                Model Bucket is ml-project
[INFO]  2020-08-22T08:18:22.685Z                Model Prefix is fastai-models/lesson1/model.tar.gz
[INFO]  2020-08-22T08:18:22.686Z                Loading model from S3
module initialization error: An error occurred (InvalidToken) when calling the GetObject operation: The provided token is malformed or otherwise invalid.
```

Comment: Is your IAM user has the MFA policy?

Comment: No, I have a root user with MFA, but the current IAM user that I'm using has the key pair for cli configuration and id/pw for AWS console.

Comment: check the credential property by calling sts get-caller-identity from your cli.

Comment: Wait...it has a different user id while all the other attribs appears to be correct. How can this happen? Thanks for the insight.
```
{
    "UserId": "<DIFFERENT_USERID>",
    "Account": <SAME_ACCOUNT_ID>,
    "Arn": "arn:aws:iam::<SAME_ARN>"
}
```

Comment: In your credentials file, your IAM user access key might be not the default profile but the custom profile then you should give the profile name to the boto3 or make it as default.

Comment: Never mind...I thought the get-caller-identity returns the access key id (prefix AKIA), which is different from the user id (prefix AIDA). It's actually the same user, and I only have a single user credential in the .aws/credentials file ([default])!

Comment: I think you have to create the Access Key and use that for API, not the user ID. User ID is used to restrict the principal when someone trying the call the API. Any reason to use the user id as key? That is not the usual way.

Comment: Sorry if my words were misleading. So I do have my access key issued & stored within the .aws/credentials, and I thought that the sts get-caller-identity returns the access key. That's why I thought it gave out a different access key when I ran that command when it was simply a user id.

Comment: You are not using MFA, or don't have to assumeRole then there not should be the token. The error says invalid token, so might be the session token is given in the credentials?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220313/discussion-between-kang-woosang-and-lamanus).

Answer (score 1):

I think your s3 bucket is not located in `ap-northeast-2` region. You can check this on the s3 console. if its not you will need to pass the region in the code as below.

```
s3 =  boto3.client('s3', region_name='ap-northeast-2')
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I've edited my code as such, and it gave out a `RequestTimeTooSkewed` error. So I synced the time with the AWS server using `sudo ntpdate -u in.pool.ntp.org` command. Now I'm getting the original error again though...

Comment: Have you tried from the terminal `aws s3 list-objects`

Comment: I've tried to identify the region through `aws s3api get-bucket-location --bucket <BUCKET-NAME>` and it returns 'ap-northeast-2'!